# Why my Nextjs <Image> component renders as jpg instead of Webp or Avif?

Tags: next.js, webp, nextjs-image, image-optimization, image-rendering

With Nextjs the expected outcome is to see the Image component rendered as .WebP or .AVIF but it remains jpg -

[image]

Below is my next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['cdn.sanity.io'],
    formats: ['image/avif', 'image/webp'],
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: [{ loader: '@svgr/webpack', options: { icon: true } }],
    });
    return config;
  }, };
```

The following is the next/image component:

```
   <Image
                          className="kitchen-img"
                          loader={myLoader}
                          loading="lazy"
                          layout="fill"
                          objectFit="cover"
                          src={urlFor(kitchen.mainImage).url()!}
                          alt={kitchen.title}
                        />
```

Any idea why the it doesn't come up as avif/webp? What am I missing?

```
const myLoader = ({ src, width, quality }: any) => {
return `${src}?w=${width}&q=${quality || 85}`  };
```

Comment: Could you share with us your loader (myLoader)? It seems like you trigger the image directly for your CDN, and is not stored in the next cache folder.

Comment: Hi Nicolae, thank your for trying to help, I've added the code of the loader above. any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, you are using a loader that will trigger the images directly from your CDN, and will not be stored in next cache folder.

To be 100% sure, try to remove the `loader={myLoader}` and check the network :) again. (test with `next dev`, and check if your image has webp extension)

If you still want to use webp, check if you can send the extension via your CDN.

```
const myLoader = ({ src, width, quality }: any) => {
  return `${src}?w=${width}&q=${quality || 85}&?fm=webp`
};
```

Keep in mind, that some browsers don't [support webp](https://caniuse.com/webp).

Comment: Bingo. when removing the loader it rendered as avif. Thank you

Comment: BTW, adding &?fm=webp will get this only webp format not avif. so what's the best practice to let it choose randomly either webp or avif using this method?

Comment: Currently, I don't have a solution for that. What you need to do, is to make a function that checks if avif / webp are compatible.